# How are the greater-than and less-than operators (`<`, `>`) interpreted when used between vectors?

Tags: rust

I tried the below variations:

`vec![5, 5, 5] > vec![1, 1, 1]` returns `true`
`vec![5] > vec![1, 1, 1]` returns `true`
`vec![5, 0] > vec![6, 1]` returns `false`
`vec![1, 5, 2] > vec![0, 6, 1]` returns `true`

It seems that only the first element is used to determine the output; vector size differences and the remaining elements are ignored from comparison. Is that how it is supposed to be?

Arrays seem to respond in the same way, the only difference is that both the arrays should be the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called [**lexicographic order**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#lexicographical-comparison). Your tests are unfortunately misleading. `vec![5, 5, 5] > vec![5, 5, 6]` returns `false`, or in general:

```rust
vec![x, y] > vec![x, y - k]   // true for any k > 0 and (y - k) valid
vec![x, y, z] > vec![x, a, b] // same result as vec![y, z] > vec![a, b]
```

Lexicographic order is a common order for collection types. Note that [`Vec`'s `Ord` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Ord) also [documents the comparison](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#lexicographical-comparison) as lexicographic.

Comment: I just tried those variations in Python and see the same behaviour. I have been coding in Python for a long time but somehow never came across this scenario. While learning Rust, I stumbled upon this. Benefits of learning a new language :)